# Reducing and ReExpanding java long type

Tags: java

I have a special use case here. My current task is to reduce large numbers like `270873547828564` to smaller numbers and be able to get back the large numbers from the small number. To achieve this I have implemented two java functions to take care of this task. Below are the functions

```
 private long reduceLong(long value) {
        return value >> 16;
    }

    private long expandReducedLong(long reduced) {
        return reduced << 16;
    }
```

Now in my main method I am calling the respective functions above as thus:

```
long reduction = reduceLong(270873547828564L);
System.out.println("Reducing 270873547828564 to " + reduction);

long reExpansion = expandReducedLong(reduction);
System.out.println("ReExpanding "+reduction +" to give "+reExpansion);
```

Below is the output in my console:

```
Reducing 270873547828564 to give 4133202328
ReExpanding 4133202328 to give 270873547767808
```

As you can see from the above results, there is a whole `60756` difference error between the real large number `270873547828564L` and the re expanded value `270873547767808L`. Is there a trick to make sure the re-expansion always produce the exact same large number that was reduced? Thanks alot for your time.

For my current use case I define a large number as any number between `5_000_000_000 and 281474976710655` and a small number as any number below or equal to `5_000_000_000`.

Comment: Why do you think your reducing method would work at all? You are discarding the least significant 16 bits. Obviously there's going to be some information lost, unless they are all 0s.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the comment. Can you suggest a better way around this? I am pretty new to Java and willing to unlearn and learn...Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you define what is a "large" number and what is a "small number"? How large is a large number and how small is a small number? Also, do you accept a solution that splits the long into 2 smaller ints?

Comment: Ok. For my current use case a large number is a number whose digit length is greater than 5_000_000_000 and a small number is any number less than or equal to 5_000_000_000  for my current use case. And all must be natural numbers as my code can't currently accept real numbers.

Comment: Can you also explain why you want to reduce the number and then get it back? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I assume you mean that a large number is a number whose _absolute value_ is greater than 5_000_000_000? Then this is impossible. There are more large numbers than small numbers, so you can't create a one to one mapping between them. What about a method that splits your large number into 2 smaller numbers? Will that solve your problem?

Comment: Splitting the large numbers into two smaller numbers seems to be a good idea, but can you show how that would work. How can the two numbers be used to reference the original large number.

Comment: I have edited my question, I have clearly defined what I meant by a large number and a small number in the footer of the question.

Comment: @AbadiEferu By your definition, numbers like -7,000,000,000 are small numbers. Is this intended? Do you count all negative numbers as small numbers?

Answer (score 0):

By your definition, there are more large numbers than small numbers, so creating a one to one mapping between them is impossible.

You can try splitting a large number into 2 small numbers instead.

A `long`, as you may know, represents numbers using 64 bits, while `int` uses 32. We can store the first 32 bits of a long into an `int` variable, and then the other 32 bits into another `int` variable.

We can do this by shifting bits and using bitwise operators:

```
private static int[] splitLargeNumber(long l) {
                       // first 32 bits     the rest 32 bits
    return new int[] { (int)(l >> 32), (int)(l & 0xffffffffL) };
}

private static long combineSmallNumbers(int[] smallNumbers) {
    return ((long)(smallNumbers[0]) << 32) + smallNumbers[1];
}
```

usage:

```
long largeNumber = 5_000_000_000L;
int[] smallNumbers = splitLargeNumber(largeNumber);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallNumbers));
System.out.println(combineSmallNumbers(smallNumbers));
```

---

If all negative numbers count as small numbers, then a one to one mapping is possible. Just subtract your large number by 281474976710655, and you will get a small number. You add 281474976710655, and you will get a large number.

```
private long reduceLong(long value) {
    return value - 281474976710655;
}

private long expandReducedLong(long reduced) {
    return reduced + 281474976710655;
}
```